# Configure linux to always keep certain amount of RAM free?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

On a linux server I have 12 GB of RAM and 4 GB of swap.

I need to configure it in such way that it always keeps certain amount of RAM free, by putting stuff into swap. For example, always keep 1 GB of RAM free.

Right now it only starts to use swap when all 12 GB of RAM are 100% filled, so that I might get situation like this:

- RAM: 12 of 12 GB used, 100% used
- Swap: 0 of 4 GB used

What I want it to do it in such situation instead is put 1 GB of data into swap:

- RAM: 11 of 12 GB used
- SWAP: 1 of 4 GB used

I have /proc/sys/vm/swappiness=60. Linux distro is Ubuntu